# Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter' when running Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.11'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13' , platform: :ruby
group :development, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
# gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
# gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
# gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

> Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'.
>   Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use
>   an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add
>   the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
>
> Blockquote

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11/lib/active_support/c ore_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use Big Decimal() method instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.11 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server [2020-03-23 23:42:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2 [2020-03-23 23:42:51] INFO  ruby 2.6.5 (2019-10-01) [x64-mingw32] [2020-03-23 23:42:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3492 port=3000
```

Comment: What does `config/database.yml` say your adapter is? Did you `bundle install`? Are you running regular Ruby or JRuby?

Comment: default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Comment: Check that `sqlite3` shows up when doing `bundle show`. Are you actually intending to use Postgres here, though?

Comment: regular ruby....

Comment: bundle show:form ruby`.
  * actionmailer (4.2.11)
  * actionpack (4.2.11)
  * actionview (4.2.11)
  * activejob (4.2.11)
  * activemodel (4.2.11)
  * activerecord (4.2.11)
  * activesupport (4.2.11)
  * arel (6.0.4)
  * binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
  * builder (3.2.4)
  * bundler (1.17.3)
  * byebug (11.1.1)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
  * crass (1.0.6)
  * debug_inspector (0.0.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)

Comment: * globalid (0.4.2)
  * i18n (0.9.5)
  * loofah (2.4.0)
  * mail (2.7.1)
  * mini_mime (1.0.2)
  * mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
  * minitest (5.14.0)
  * nokogiri (1.10.9)
  * pg (1.2.3)
  * rack (1.6.13)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (4.2.11)
  * rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1
  * rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
  * rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
  * railties (4.2.11)
  * rake (13.0.1)
  * sprockets (4.0.0)
  * sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.13)
  * thor (1.0.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.6)
  * tzinfo (1.2.6)
  * tzinfo-data (1.2019.3)
  * web-console (2.3.0)

Comment: Don't need to post everything, just asking about `sqlite3`. Looks like it's having trouble loading that dependency so may need to uninstall and reinstall that gem.

Comment: bundle show sqlite3:

Comment: The dependency sqlite3 (= 1.3.13) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler
 is installing for. Bundler is installing for x64-mingw32 but the dependency is
only for ruby. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-plat
form ruby`.
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32

Comment: rails s:C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11/lib/active_support/c
ore_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use Big
Decimal() method instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.11 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2020-03-23 23:26:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2
[2020-03-23 23:26:48] INFO  ruby 2.6.5 (2019-10-01) [x64-mingw32]
[2020-03-23 23:26:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3948 port=3000

Comment: When you click "add a comment" there is placeholder text that says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid answering questions in comments.**" All of the information you've been slamming into comments is essentially unreadable; please stop trying to post code in comments and do what the placeholder says to do: put this content _into your original post_.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a documentation for `platform` usage on `Gemfile`: https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS

It says:

> ruby
>
> C Ruby (MRI), Rubinius or TruffleRuby, but NOT Windows

Your `sqlite3` dependency is for `ruby` platform, so on Windows it does not get installed.

And you seem on Windows. Therefore `sqlite3` does not get installed.